# Parameters and computational time of epoch increases with the increasing channels of input image?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have different sets of images at input (i.e. 56x56x3, 56x56x5, 56x56x10, 56x56x30, 56x56x61) with the same network.
1) I want to know that the number of parameters of network will be same for each input?
2) Computational time of each epoch is slightly higher by increasing the number of channels at input, is it normal?

**UPDATE**

```
Parameter calculation for 3 channels
3*3*3*64 = 1728
3*3*64*128 = 73728
3*3*128*256 = 294912
5*5*256*512 = 3276800
1*1*512*1024 = 524288
1*1*1024*4 = 4096

Parameter calculation for 10 channels
3*3*10*64 = 5760
3*3*64*128 = 73728
3*3*128*256 = 294912
5*5*256*512 = 3276800
1*1*512*1024 = 524288
1*1*1024*4 = 4096
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performing convolution it is necessary that any kernel (or filter) has the same number of channels as the input feature map (or image), for the corresponding layer. And the number of parameters for that layer is given as:

```
No of Kernels x Kernel Height x Kernel Width x No of Channels in the Kernel
```

So you see that the number of parameters are actually directly proportional to the number of channels in the input feature map. And it is obvious that as the number of parameters increase the number of computations also increase, hence the increased computational time.

You may see the detailed explanation of convolution operation in my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45999157/understanding-the-caffe-convolutional-layer/46000528#46000528).

Comment: How can i calculate the computational time for each of the input?

Comment: That is slightly complex. You need to find the number and types of computations involved for each input. Then find the number of CPU/GPU cycles taken for each of those computations. Then there are overheads for data read, write and transfer across memory, CPU and GPU. Once you have figured all that out, plug in the clock frequency of your CPU/GPU to get the time in seconds. Even after all this you will only get an approximation.

Comment: So is it fine to show that the computational is increases by showing the increase computing the parameters?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: Do we need to add bias with weights to calculate parameters?

Comment: No, you don't need to add bias.

Comment: I have updated my question with the calculation of parameter. Can you please confirm me that its correct?

Comment: For convolution layers it seems correct but is there an FC layer in the end?

Comment: Yes, 2 FC layers `1*1*512*1024` and `1*1*1024*4`

Comment: For FC use this: Input Height x Input Width x Input Depth x FC Layer Size. where input is the output of the previous layer. So you'll get bigger numbers for FC.

Comment: I coudn't understand that, can you please show me from the above example

Comment: So what is the output of the pooling layer prior to your first FC? Take those dimensions as input.

Comment: its Pool [2,2], stride 2 and pad 0
So it will be 2*2*512*1024?

Comment: No, what is the output feature map size of pooling layer?

Comment: I have updated the question with image of final layer and first FC layer

Comment: Ok so 2*2*512*1024 is correct for the first FC layer.

Comment: And for the second FC layer 1024*4.